# Wordpress get_posts that exist in all listed categories

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a customized function to search posts where user is allowed to check on the categories.

Let's say I have two posts with:

1. Post1 [cat1]
2. Post2 [cat1][cat2]

Here are my scenarios:

1. When only cat1 is checked, Post1 and Post2 should be returned.
2. When both cat1 and cat2 are checked, only Post2 should be returned.

Can I achieve this when calling `get_posts` from wordpress codex?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it, post your code if you run into problems.

Comment: Starting place: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) here is the example:

> Multiple Category Handling
>
> Display posts that are in multiple categories. This shows posts that
>   are in both categories 2 and 6:

```
$category_array = [2, 6]; // you can get this via $_POST variable
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'category__and' => $category_array
));
```

After query you can loop through [WP_LOOP](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

Comment: Thanks. Guess I have to use WP_Query

Comment: No, you don't have to. The [documentation of `wp_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters) explicitly states that it accepts the parameters of `WP_Query`. That's why I gave you the link to it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes it's true that `wp_posts` uses WP_Query in backend but `wp_posts` does not have `category__and` argument in it. [See] (https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters)

Comment: @TouqeerShafi Did you read the second paragraph of that section? Why don't you try it?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider category parameter states that "Note: The category parameter can be a comma separated list of categories, as the get_posts() function passes the 'category' parameter directly into `WP_Query` as 'cat'. " and if you see in `WP_Query` `cat` parameter operates as OR operator but `category__and` operate as `AND` operator